# Python Password Input with If condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

So just learning python, have this trouble with if/else and input , task is easy and think is only a simple solution but already got stuck, below is my code, but keeps printing invalid even when info is correct what is wrong?

```
user= input("Please enter your user")
pw= input("Please enter Password")

if user == "Lena" and pw == "123456":
    print("Successfully Logged In")
else:
    print("Invalid Credentials")
```

Comment: Have you tried printing debug messages or using a debugger ?

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you make sure the `L` in `Lena` is uppercase when you enter it?

Comment: Working fine, at least the edited question by @quamrana

Comment: Working fine. Please check the typo while entering data.

Comment: You could also add `print` statements to show you what the program got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your above code seems to work fine for what you're trying to achieve.

It could be as [Omer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694402/python-password-input-with-if-condition/60694569#comment107383753_60694402) said, that you put in a lowercase `L` in `Lena`.

If you want your usernames to be case insensitive try this:

```
user= input("Please enter your user\n")
pw= input("Please enter Password\n")

if user.lower() == "lena" and pw == "123456":
    print("Successfully Logged In")
else:
    print("Invalid Credentials")


Please enter your user
LENA

Please enter Password
123456
Successfully Logged In
```

`.lower()` is a string method which makes all of the letters in a string lowercase. Then you can check it to a lowercase string.

You can also use `.upper()` for a similar effect.